# Ember.js todo app handlebars template issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm very new to Ember and am trying to follow the ToDo app tutorial. However, I am having a hard time generating a handlebar script in my index.html file. Here is what the index file looks pre-handlebars script

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ember.js • TodoMVC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
    <section id="todoapp">
      <header id="header">
        <h1>todos</h1>
        <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
      </header>

      <section id="main">
        <ul id="todo-list">
          <li class="completed">
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>Learn Ember.js</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>...</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>Profit!</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
      </section>

      <footer id="footer">
        <span id="todo-count">
          <strong>2</strong> todos left
        </span>
        <ul id="filters">
          <li>
            <a href="all" class="selected">All</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="active">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="completed">Completed</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <button id="clear-completed">
          Clear completed (1)
        </button>
      </footer>
    </section>

    <footer id="info">
      <p>Double-click to edit a todo</p>
    </footer>

    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-1.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js"></script>
    <script src="js/router.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I wrap the handlebars script tag within the body element, the other HTML elements are not rendered properly. The code doesn't run in my browser and I suspect the script is missing a closing element somewhere. I'm not sure where. Does anyone have any pointers. Much appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
    <section>
    <section id="todoapp">
      <header id="header">
        <h1>todos</h1>
        <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
      </header>

      <section id="main">
        <ul id="todo-list">
          <li class="completed">
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>Learn Ember.js</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>...</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>Profit!</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
      </section>

      <footer id="footer">
        <span id="todo-count">
          <strong>2</strong> todos left
        </span>
        <ul id="filters">
          <li>
            <a href="all" class="selected">All</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="active">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="completed">Completed</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <button id="clear-completed">
          Clear completed (1)
        </button>
      </footer>
    </section>

    <footer id="info">
      <p>Double-click to edit a todo</p>
    </footer>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what the issue is, but I would check that all of your js files are being properly loaded. I actually tried the ToDo demo from [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/adding-a-route-and-template/) that used JS Bin and I didn't see that it was working. However, after taking that code and placing into a jsfiddle where the sources are loaded in the `<head>` tag, it actually worked.

Here's a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3tBQ) and here a link to the [live version](http://jsfiddle.net/J3tBQ/show). I would inspect the output on the second link and see what the differences are between that and your code.

Hope you get your question resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while working through the Tutorial.
The trick is in the order of the script includes.  Make sure that the framework dependencies are included first and then the application.js and finally the router.js.  See below:

```
<!-- ... Ember.js and other javascript dependencies ... -->
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>
<script src="js/router.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't write html on < script > element !!

Comment: Then how else are you suppose to include the handlebars script tag within the index.html file? I'm confused.

Comment: @abdulrhman, could you add some more specifics for GabeLafontant so that he can fix the issue? I'll add an answer to see if we can get this question solved...

Comment: I don't have an answer but am thoroughly confused by the commenters answer. From every tutorial I've seen you place the handlebars template within the index.html file. That script tag usually has some html as well as handlebars helpers. Why can't you write html within the element? Here is the link http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/adding-a-route-and-template/

Comment: After looking at that page, it doesn't seem that the problem is the html within the `<script>` tag...

Comment: @abdulrhman, you most definitely can write html inside of a script tag.  It isn't evaluated by the browser as dom, but it's used as a way of inserting templates etc.

Comment: I figured out what the root of my was. I was not loading my dependencies with proper file path in the index.html file. This is the reason why none of the html was rendered.